# undefined reference to function when compiling using makefiles C

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run some experiments using a set of functions inside a file called `coco.c` (from the coco optimisation platform which can be found at https://github.com/numbbo/coco). This file also comes with a header file `coco.h`. I have been trying to test if the calling functions from the `coco.c` file works by writing my own file called `testing.c`.

The full testing.c file can be seen below

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "coco.h"

#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))


int main(void){
 coco_suite_t *suite;
 suite = coco_suite("bbob-biobj", "", "");
 return 0;
}
```

I have placed placed both `coco.h` and `coco.c` in the same folder as `testing.c` along with my `Makefile.in`. `coco_suite` is a function inside `coco.c`.

The makefile that I have been using can be seen below (most of which I have copied from the example makefile).

```
## Makefile

LDFLAGS += -lm
CCFLAGS ?= -g -ggdb --std+c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -Wno-sign-compare -Wconversion


all: testing

clean:
    rm -f coco.o
    rm -f testing.o testing


testing: testing.o coco.o
    gcc ${CCFLAGS} -o testing coco.o testing.o ${LDFLAGS}

coco.o: coco.h coco.c
    gcc -c ${CCFLAGS} -o coco.o coco.c

testing.o: coco.h coco.c testing.c
    gcc -c ${CCFLAGS} -o testing.o testing.c
```

However, when attempting to build the executable I get an error saying undefined reference to `coco_suite`. I know that the function prototype is in the header file and the full code is in the source file as I have successfully run the example provided by the authors of the coco platform. I have doublechecked the whitespace (tabs vs spaces etc) and it matches exactly with the working example provided. However even when I copy and paste the example code into the `testing.c` file I get the same error.

This leads me to believe that the issue is in the makefile but I cant see what it is.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Your `testing.o` should not depend on `coco.c`. Instead `coco.o` should depend on `coco.c`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for your response. I have edited the code block and re-ran it. Does the coco.c still need to be taken out of the `testing.o` dependencies?

Comment: You do not use `coco.c` to build `testing.o`. If you don't remove it, you might build `testing.o` even if neither `testing.c` nor `coco.h` were modified.

Comment: I have removed it and I'm still getting the error of undefined reference to `coco_suite` when running `make testing`.

Comment: Please show relevant content of `coco.c` and `coco.h`. Do you have some typos? Do you have some code disabled by macros?

Comment: I cant post the code that defines the `coco_suite` function in this box as it is tool long. I have the example experiment provided by the authors of the platform and that calls the same function from the same file with a similar makefile with no errors.

Comment: I can compile the executable in the terminal myself just using a few gcc commands and manually putting in the dependencies but for some reason using the make file doesn't work.

Comment: I bet if you delete all the code from inside `coco_suite` then you still get the same problem and the code is shorter. Which means you can post the code where most of it is deleted.

Comment: If it works from the command line and not from the makefile, just look at the command line make prints and compare it to the one that works.  What are the differences?  One of those differences must be causing the problem.  Make doesn't compile or link your code, the compiler/linker does.  There's nothing make can do to enable this to work, or not work, other than invoke the command line you provided it.

Comment: Run `nm -g coco.o` and look for `coco_suite` in the output.  If it is not there, it means there is something up with the way you compiled `coco.c`.  If it is there, then it will be surprising.